# How do I correctly make a RegQueryValueEx call in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I am new to c++ and trying to get a string value out of a registry key of type reg_sz in Visual c++ 6.0. Fair to say I am out of my depth and I think I am missing some fairly obvious stuff.

```
string FindRegistryValue(){
    string location;
    LONG lResult;
    LPBYTE installLocation;
    LPDWORD bufferSize= (unsigned long*)8192;
    lResult = RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\1234\\uninstallString", 
        NULL, NULL, installLocation, bufferSize);
    location = *installLocation;
    return location;
}
```

It compiles however gives off an access violation during the call to RegQueryValueEx. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
LPBYTE installLocation;
LPDWORD bufferSize = (unsigned long*)8192;
```

it should really be:

```
BYTE installLocation[8192];
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof installLocation;
```

then `bufferSize` should be changed to `&bufferSize` in the `RegQueryValueEx` call.

Further, the returned data is not guaranteed to be null-terminated. So you  need to deal with that too:

```
if (bufferSize && !installLocation[bufferSize - 1])
    --bufferSize;
return string(installLocation, bufferSize);
```

Comment: On the other hand, the value will *usually* be null terminated, since that is the documented format for `REG_SZ` and most people follow it. You could check if the character at `installLocation[bufferSize-1]` is null and if so then decrement `bufferSize` before calling `string(installLocation, bufferSize)`. Or use [`RegGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868.aspx) to guarantee `installLocation` is null terminated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, I agree with just using `RegGetValue` if the OP could work with that.

Comment: Just know that `RegGetValue()` is not available on XP SP2 and earlier. For SP2, you can use [`SHRegGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773536.aspx), though.

Comment: Surely, these days XPSP3 and/or Vista must be the minimum baseline? :-P

Comment: One more question. For the if block why is it treating bufferSize and installLocation like booleans? How does that check for the null terminate? For some reason this code is outputting funny looking 'ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ' symbols.

Comment: @en93 Numbers and pointers are "convertible to boolean" in C and C++, where 0 and nullptr are false, and everything else is true. In this case, the code is the same as `bufferSize != 0 && installLocation[bufferSize - 1] == 0`. But I hate having to write those out "long-hand"; this is C++, not Java. :-P